# Web.config file size limit reached

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am facing a problem, My client has the following system configuration:

1. Windows Server 2016 DataCenter
2. IIS version 10
3. SharePoint Server 2016

The problem is that the web.config file has been reached to its limit of 250KB, after reading several blogs and articles (all based on .NET application) I came to know two solutions:

1. Increase the file size limit from registry editor, which is not available for IIS 10.
2. We can Split the following sections of web.config to separated files:

   - AppSettings
   - ConnectionStrings
   - SafeControls
   - Bindings
   - Client

As SharePoint Add/Remove WebParts info of SafeControls into web.config and my project has several WebParts, web.config becomes larger and finally at one stage due to the size limit of 250KB web site producing 500 Internal Server Error.

It looks simple to rectify the problem that I can separate the SafeControl Section but after that if I add/remove WSPs will SharePoint handle the separated file or still it will update web.config, any idea from anyone?

Comment: After further experiments on web.config, I found that SharePoint does not handle separated file and add SafeControl entries in the web.config file, which is resulting in web site generating Parser Error Message: A section using 'configSource' may contain no other attributes or elements.


Please note that I am working on Configuration database version16.0.4405.1000